# Accessing to the users uid in Firebase

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have this JSON structure:

```
     {
"Devices" : {
"1EJ8QmEQBJfBez7PMADbftCjVff1" : {
  "Device1" : {
    "Category" : "Others",
    "Description" : "",
    "DeviceName" : "",
    "ImageUrl" : ""
  },
  "Device2" : {
    "Category" : "Chairs",
    "Description" : "",
    "DeviceName" : "",
    "ImageUrl" : ""
  },
  "Device3" : {
    "Category" : "Others",
    "Description" : "",
    "DeviceName" : "",
    "ImageUrl" : ""
  }
},
"97PUAcUC5UYxLpBOLnC4yQjxiEf2" : {
  "Device1" : {
    "Category" : "Others",
    "Description" : "",
    "DeviceName" : "",
    "ImageUrl" : ""
  },
  "Device2" : {
    "Category" : "Books",
    "Description" : "",
    "DeviceName" : "",
    "ImageUrl" : ""
  },
  "Device3" : {
    "Category" : "Chairs",
    "Description" : "",
    "DeviceName" : "",
    "ImageUrl" : ""
    }
   }
  },
 "UserProfile" : {
"1EJ8QmEQBJfBez7PMADbftCjVff1" : {
  "city" : "",
  "email" : "",
  "name" : "",
  "phone" : ""
},
"97PUAcUC5UYxLpBOLnC4yQjxiEf2" : {
  "city" : "",
  "email" : "",
  "name" : "",
  "phone" : ""
   },
 }
}
```

I want to access to the Category node in each device? 
Is that possible?
Because I want to retrieve data for all nodes that have the same category!

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Devices")

    ref.queryOrderedByChild("Category")
```

I have tried to access to devices! then direct to the category! 
It seems like this is not the correct way!

Don't tell me that I need to change the structure of the JSON!

Is there any way to access to the user ids'?

Comment: There isn't a wildcard mechanism so I think you would have to restructure.

Comment: The recommendation is to flatten data structures and also incorporate redundancy - https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

Comment: there is but you need to do it in code once you have all the devices.

Answer (score 0):

In NoSQL databases you will often have to model your data for the use-cases that you app needs. With your current data structure you can efficiently load a user's devices.

To also efficiently allow to load the devices for a category, you will have to store that information too. Here's one way to do that:

```
"Categories": {
  "Others": {
    "1EJ8QmEQBJfBez7PMADbftCjVff1_Device1": "1EJ8QmEQBJfBez7PMADbftCjVff1/Device1",
    "1EJ8QmEQBJfBez7PMADbftCjVff1_Device3": "1EJ8QmEQBJfBez7PMADbftCjVff1/Device3",
    "97PUAcUC5UYxLpBOLnC4yQjxiEf2_Device1": "97PUAcUC5UYxLpBOLnC4yQjxiEf2/Device1"
  },
  "Chairs": {
    "1EJ8QmEQBJfBez7PMADbftCjVff1_Device2": "1EJ8QmEQBJfBez7PMADbftCjVff1/Device2",
    "97PUAcUC5UYxLpBOLnC4yQjxiEf2_Device3": "97PUAcUC5UYxLpBOLnC4yQjxiEf2/Device3"
  },
  "Books": {
    "97PUAcUC5UYxLpBOLnC4yQjxiEf2_Device2": "97PUAcUC5UYxLpBOLnC4yQjxiEf2/Device2"
  }

}
```

So the above structure uses `<uid>_<devicekey>` as the keys and then has the path to that item under `/devices` as its value.

I recommend reading this great article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: You have to augment the data structure to allow the query you want. The sooner you accept that, the sooner you can get over the frowny face.

Comment: Cool. Can you share that as a self-answer? That might make this page more useful to developers who struggle with the same problem in the future.